# how to get callback from twitter after tweet in browser

Tags: android, twitter

I have problem for twitter callback to  myapp

when i share `image` and `text` to `twitter(Twitter application not installed)` that time it redirect to browser for sharing `image` or `text`.

sharing is perfect but problem is that its not sending any callback event to my app and doesn't close the browser automatically.

```
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="pdk1234567890" />
                <data
                    android:host="SampleActivity"
                    android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Please Help...

Comment: Have the same issue here. Find any solution? if yes please help me too.

Comment: Right now i have no solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily. I did it using [FinestWebView](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android) (it's UI can be modified to look alike twitter) but you can use normal phone browser for it. 
and it's working. Check the below code.

```
 String url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello World!";
 new FinestWebView.Builder(activity)
                .toolbarColorRes(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .showIconMenu(false)
                .titleColorRes(R.color.White)
                .backPressToClose(true)
                .iconDefaultColorRes(R.color.White)
                .addWebViewListener(new WebViewListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(url);
                        if (url.contains("complete")) { 
                         //TODO On Success Code
                        } else {
                           //TODO On Failure Code
                        }
                    }
                }).show(url);
```

**Explanation**: I am tracking the URL of the tweet and finding the keyword "complete" which appears in the URL when you successfully tweet.